# Having trouble with removing elements from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm making a song guessing game of which my code would generate a number from 0 to the amount of elements in a list of artists, it would then index that number and use it on the songs array to grab the corresponding song (I know very bad but it would take a lifetime to restructure) Here is the code;

```
ArtCount = len(artist)
for x in range (ArtCount):
    print(ArtCount)
    count = len(artist)
    randNum = int(random.randint(0, count - 1))
    randArt = artist[randNum]
    ArtInd = artist.index(randArt)# catches element position                          
    songSel = songs[randNum]
    print (randNum)
    print ("The artist is " + randArt)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    songie = songSel
    print( "The songs first letter be " + songSel[0])
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("")
    question = input("What song do you believe it to be? ")
    if question == (songSel):
        songs.remove(songSel)
        artist.remove(randArt)
        print ("Correct")
        print ("Next Question")
```

So what this is does is when you get it right the  code will remove the song and artist just used to prevent dupes, when the code runs, you see this;

```
 10
 2
 The artist is Jonh Denver
 The songs first letter be C

 What song do you believe it to be? *dsjhgdjf*

 Wrong, 1 questions wrong, careful!

 10
 3
 The artist is Lil Nas X
 The songs first letter be P

 What song do you believe it to be? *Panini*
 Correct
 Next Question
 +4 Points

 10
 2
 The artist is Jonh Denver
 The songs first letter be C

 What song do you believe it to be? *Country Roadsa*

 Wrong, 2 questions wrong, careful!

 10
 5
 The artist is NSG
 The songs first letter be O

 What song do you believe it to be? *OT Bop*
 Correct
 Next Question
 +3 Points
```

The first number is the length of the artists, the second is the random selection for my purpose, it had worked before and I've tried changing and deleting what I've added from my last version but nothing has worked.

Comment: I don't have the time to dig into your problem but a few things you can do to clarify your code: don't abbreviate your variable names ; use snake_case instead of camelCase in python ; extract instructions into functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem should be the

```
    ArtCount = len(artist)
```

as this value does not change and gets printed repeatedly.
You see it here:

```
    abcd = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    LEN = len(abcd)
    for i in range(LEN):
        print(LEN)
        abcd.remove(abcd[0])
        print(len(abcd))
```

where the second value printed will reduce but the LEN does not.
The solution for that would be updating ArtCount in the loop. 
But this still does not explain, why "John Denver" can pop up twice, except this value would be in the list more than once ?

Comment: Thank you, putting ArtCount again in the loop fixed it.